# Why water or condensation in a narrow neck open bottle can't seem to evaporate completely?

Tags: evaporation

When I clean a soda bottle with water, empty the water out and leave the bottle open for days and the inside wall of the bottle seems to stay "wet" not "dry"?

Comment: A photograph would be useful. Consider also removing a sample of the material and seeing if it dries even in the open.

Comment: Yes, more details would help: Is the bottle glass or plastic?  (Glass is hydrophilic; PET plastic is hydrophilic.) What shape and size? (There is no universal "soda bottle".) Is the bottle vertical or on its side? (Water vapour is lighter than dry air.) Indoors or outdoors? Exposed to sun? Does this happen throughout the year or just in certain seasons?

Comment: It's a plastic spray bottle made by Zep "Professional Sprayer 32 Oz Capacity" Product code: HDPRO1 ([link](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Zep-32-oz-Plastic-Spray-Bottle/3621238?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lwn-_-ggl-_-LIA_LWN_127_Cleaning-_-3621238-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI053mqNe2_AIV0AitBh216g8CEAQYAiABEgL5ffD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few factors that contribute to evaporation for example temperature, surface area, humidity, and wind speed. In your house where I assume the bottle is not hot enough and probably too humidity to completely evaporate the water inside. If you would like to get all the water out, drying the inside further so the water that is left is thin ie more surface area. If you leave it outside on a nice warm and dry day, the water will evaporate.